# Hinge with part perpendicular to other

Tags: hinges

I'm searching for the name of a hinge that looks like this for my project:

[image: Perpendicular hinge]

Middle part should be able to turn almost 90 degrees on both sides. Does this kind of hinge exists and if so, does it have a name so I can find it more easily?

I made the picture myself by the way. If I can't find a hinge like this I will probably have to make it myself by welding a metal plate on the back of it. I'm trying to avoid that because I don't have welding or soldering tools.

Comment: What is it being used for?

Comment: I want to make a wooden bike. Instead of the head tube with the steering rod inserted in it, I'll screw the hinge between the frame and the steering rod. Hard to describe but I don't know the terms. Not sure if that's a good idea but it's my only one.

Comment: Buy two and bolt them together back to back. Pick a design where the holes are mirrored so they line up properly. You won't get a full 90 degrees because of the nut/bolt profile sticking out a bit, so pick the slimmest nuts/bolts you can find and hinges with the holes as far from the pivot point as possible.

Comment: I don't see how your project calls for 3 leaves. A single hinge should do.

Comment: @isherwood That's actually 2 leaves but the back one is double width. I feel like if it was normal it would be weaker because it's asymmetric, maybe I'm wrong

Comment: It wouldn't have to be asymmetric. I thought of that, too. You could let it into the end of your "top tube" member and cross-bolt it.

Comment: Thing is, a basic pin hinge has a lot of play. Your bike's front end will be very rattle and a little unnerving to ride. Bicycle heads use adjustable ball bearings for a reason.

Comment: If you are making a "wooden bike" why don't you make a wooden headset? Use a wood dowel that runs through a wood block headframe, you could even lubricate it with bear grease to stay "in period".

Comment: The hole in the frame will considerably weaken the frame and without ball bearings the movement will probably be harder. The wood will also wear faster.

Comment: You could put bearings on wood components... whatever, I think the hinge idea is goofy and won't work. You need the front wheel to spin/turn on a fixed axis inline with the handlebars. With a hinge, the fork/wheel assembly will actually *move* left and right on an arc...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I'm picturing wrong what you're trying to do, but perhaps a cabinet hinge like this?

[image]

I don't know if that hinge will be strong or robust enough for your application.  Cabinet hinges don't really have to endure much force.  You might be better served with what is apparently (aptly) called a "center-mount hinge":

[image]

Which sandwiches whatever is supposed to pivot.

Comment: Pictures are not working. Center-mount hinges would probably work well but they seem pretty expensive ($25+)

Comment: Picture 1:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/22c7D.jpg

Picture 2:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtAia.jpg

Do those work?

Comment: Yes it works thanks. The 25$ one looks like [this](http://www.boerboelgatesystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/73024423_Silo_1000x1000.jpg) but that would still be too weak.